# Is it possible to fwrite in binary with two different types at the same function?

Tags: c, binary, fwrite

Hello I have to make a program that involves writing a matrix in a binary file, but it has to have a space between every number written. Also the first fwrite has to have the size of the lines and columns. So instead of making something like:

```
fwrite( &n, sizeof( int ), 1, fw ); 
fwrite( &space, sizeof( char ), 1, fw ); 
fwrite( &m, sizeof( int ), 1, fw );
```

or

```
space = ' ';
fwrite( &temp, sizeof( int ), 1, fw );
fwrite( &sapce, sizeof( char ), 1, fw );
```

I wanted to see if something like this, would be possible.

```
fwrite( "&n &m", 2*sizeof( int ) + sizeof( char ), 1, fw );

fwrite( "&n ", sizeof( int ) + sizeof( char ), 1, fw );
```

Comment: When you tried it, what went wrong?

Comment: I don't have the error that I got last time I used it. I do not know if I wrote it differently before, but it seems that what I've just written does indeed work( I thought about it while writing this question ). Strange

Comment: You can try to use `sprintf()` or `snprinf()` to write whatever you want in the format you want into a buffer.  Then you can use `fwrite()` to write the whole buffer into a file.

Comment: I seems  you do not need Space. Simply you write in the num of rows, num of columns and value of elements....

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this:

```
    char a[256];
    sprintf(a, "%d %d", n, m);
    fwrite( a, strlen(a), 1, fw );
```